# algorithm to find relationship of two twitter users

Tags: algorithm, twitter, relationship

I have a 6 degrees of Kevin Bacon type problem. Lets say I have 2 twitter users and I want to figure out their relationship to each other through friends (I use friends to denote when you follow someone vs them following you) and followers in twitter. I have all id's in my database.

So for example:

Joel and Sally

Joel follows Fred who is friends with Steve who follows Sally.

There could be multiple ways to get there, but I want the shortest.

This seems like a well known computer science problem (shortest path algorihm).

Today I have a table called "influencers" where all my twitter ids are stored, then I have a followings table that is a self referential table (ids of followers on one side and friends on the other.)

So is this graph theory? If so can someone point me to any utilities/libraries/approaches that can be helpful. Im using ruby, but can parse most languages.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, it is a well known problem, as you can see in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Just notice that in your case, the weights in all edges are equal to 1), so I don't think that Djikstra's algorithm would be very useful to you.

In order to find the minimum distance, I would suggest a breadth-first search. The problem is that the Twitter network may be extremelly connected and hence you may have a combinatorial explosion (imagine that each person is connected to 20 other persons - in the first level, you would visit 20 profiles, while in the next you would visit 400, and in the next 8000 - if you don't find Sally fast, you quickly will run out of memory).

There is also a linear programming formulation, with which I am not 100% familiar. [These notes](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/LinearProgramming?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=lp.pdf) are good on linear programming, but not on the shortest path problem, while [these](http://www.princeton.edu/~rvdb/542/lectures/lec12.pdf) seem more focused on the applications.

There is a [video lecture](http://videolectures.net/mit6046jf05_demaine_lec18/) on this problem available on line that seem quite complete.

I hope these references help.

Comment: He will not run out of memory. BFS is O(N) memory-wise (consider that in BFS You mark visited nodes, and never again enqueue them)

Comment: The problem is that tweeter users may have hundreds of connections (20 was an extremelly conservative estimation, I believe), so even O(N) may be quite high if the distance and the connection number are high.

Comment: several of the twitter users have 1m followers, dozens in our database have hundreds of thousands of users.

Comment: Maybe, in this case, you could consider iterative deepening depth first search.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need BFS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

<strike>**Online approach:**</strike>
<strike>I think it can expensive depending on how you want to use it. 
On worst case you would iterate all the data in the database: cost runtime `O(n)` (assume you have a lookup function to find the user in the graph in runtime `O(1)`).</strike>

**Offline approach**
You could do offline scheduled pre-calculation and store the distances as a lookup function but it requires some additional memory `O(n*n)` where n is number of users. The cost for the lookup function is now only `O(1)` or `O(logn)` depending on how you implement it 
*(disregarding the offline runtime which I would think will be in the area `O(n)` to `O(n*n)`)*.

**Strategy**
The strategy you want to follow can be depended on number of users you can expect as an upper limit and how well the users are connected to each other. If you have few users, online approach might be fine, if you have million of users, then you probably need an offline approach but it will cost you some memory.

**Other considerations**

- Mix online and offline approach
- Use caching strategies
- Whenever a new reference is updated for a user, update the distance lookup function

---

***Updated Answer*** There are 17 mio. users, we will need offline approach.

I would follow the offline version. You should avoid `O(n*n)` runtime which I think is possible.

**DB model**

You should think how you would model the DB as this will be the most expensive part of this implementation.

Maybe something like:
Create a table for every user (table-name could be userId). And every table has entries for every user (the record key is userId).
This will result in 17 mio. tables with 17 mio. entries each (This is the `O(n*n)` cost).

**Offline** you run the BFS once while keeping track of which user you have visited and at which level you are in the BFS iteration and save the distance to the DB. I haven't thought this part through but I think this strategy is feasible. Remember to run BFS on every node, i.e. until you have visited all the users. 
If this strategy is not feasible then you could run BFS from every node which is `O(n*n)` runtime. This means it could take something like a month to run on worst case, i.e. your distance data could be old. How fast this runs depends on how connected your users are.

Or you could do the approach if possible "Whenever a new reference is updated for a user, update the distance lookup function". This would run BFS once which is  `O(n)`, i.e. a few seconds. Invoke BFS(userId) on first time event and afterwards on reference update.

**Online** you fetch the table by table-name using userId and fetch the entry by another userId to get the distance.

Comment: When You have a million users, O(n*n) is definitely too much.